# Is it possible to vulneribility while building a React app?

Tags: reactjs

Error: link is a void element tag and must neither have `children` nor use `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`.

How can I fix that error?

Comment: add code snippet which gives error

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow! Do take a moment to familiarize yourself with the site's [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking)! It would seem like your question is related to your code. Could you please edit your question to include the relevant code which causes this error?

Comment: The error message suggests that you have a `<link>` element to which you're either giving children (e.g. `<link><p>this is a child</p></link>`) or using `<link dangerouslySetInnerHTML={...}>`

Comment: when I tried to npm install react-router-dom, I got result showing 1 vulnerability found but I could not fix it